# How to find MIN and MAX of int values as substrings in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, max, min

For example, I have the following table:

```
  pc   |   cd
---------------
  pc0  |   4x
  pc1  |   24x
  pc2  |   8x
  pc3  |   4x
  pc4  |   24x
```

I need to get something like this:

```
 cd_max
--------
   24x
```

or get it sorted:

```
  pc   |   cd
---------------
  pc0  |   4x
  pc3  |   4x
  pc2  |   8x
  pc1  |   24x
  pc4  |   24x
```

'24x' is obviously string but I need to get maximum/minimum of integers inside it.

I'm using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's OK to assume the string will always just end in `x`, I'd cut it off, convert the string to a number, find the maximum and slap the `x` back on:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(LEFT(cd, LEN(cd) - 1) AS INT)) + 'x'
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replece `'x'` only keep the int. the compare or get max.

```
SELECT CONCAT(MAX(CAST(REPLACE(cd,'x','') as int)) , 'x') cd_max
FROM T
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM T
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(cd,'x','') AS INT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slice of the trailing `x` and cast the `varchar` to an `int` as follows:

```
cast(left(cd, len(cd) - 1) as int)
```

Now you can order by this value and pick the largest:

```
select top 1 cd as cd_max
from my_table
order by cast(left(cd, len(cd) - 1) as int) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

schema:

```
create table Detail (pc varchar(100) ,cd varchar(100) );
insert into Detail values ('pc0','4x');
insert into Detail values ('pc1','24x');
insert into Detail values ('pc2','8x');
insert into Detail values ('pc3','4x');
insert into Detail values ('pc4','24x');
```

sql: I assume that only last char isn't digit

```
  select * from Detail order by cast(left(cd,len(cd)-1) as int)
```

output:

```
pc  cd
pc0 4x
pc3 4x
pc2 8x
pc4 24x
pc1 24x
```

sql2: to get max cd

```
select top(1) cd as cd_max from Detail order by cast(left(cd,len(cd)-1) as int) desc
```

output:

```
cd_max
24x
```